# How to define gradle task for several child modules?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an android project that contains different library modules. I defined a task which uploads artifacts to a maven repository. It works when I define it directly in the `build.gradle` of the modules. What I would like to do is to define the task once in the parents `build.gradle` and reuse it in each module.

I followed the guide [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:injected_configuration) to write following build configuration:

My project setup is like this:

```
parent_project
|- module1
|- module2
|- module3
```

parent/build.gradle, default

```
subprojects {    
    task installToLocalMaven(type: Upload) {
        description "Installs artifacts to local Maven repository"
        configuration = configurations['archives']
        repositories {
            mavenDeployer {
                pom.groupId = commonGroupId
                pom.artifactId = artifactId
                pom.version = gitBranch() + '-' + android.defaultConfig.versionName
                if (android.defaultConfig.versionName.endsWith("-SNAPSHOT")) {
                    snapshotRepository(url: repositories.mavenLocal().url)
                } else {
                    repository(url: repositories.mavenLocal().url)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

project(':module1') {
    ext.artifactId = "module1"
}
...
```

Executing `gradlew :module1:installToLocalMaven` leads to this Error `Configuration with name 'archives' not found.`

I assume that the configuration object from the parent project is used.

How can I make sure that the configurations object of the child module is used from within the parents `build.gradle`?

Comment: have you seen gradle-fury yet? looks like it does everything you need and more

Answer (score 0):

You can use the task's `project` property. Just add `task.project.` in front of the sub-project object you are trying to access like this:

```
configuration = task.project.configurations['archives']
```

Comment: I tried this but it results in an unknown property Error for task